# Inspecting Java Map with Eclipse: Display key and value in Variables view's Value column

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have recently started to use Eclipse after using IntelliJ for a few years.  When debugging Map using IntelliJ, if the key or object implements `toString()`, a nice list of string representation of key-value is displayed.

In Eclipse, when I select **Show Logical Structure**, I see something like the following:

[image]

With this view, **the problem is that you will need to expand each entry** to see the actual key and value.  If you need to find something in a map of more than 10 elements, it becomes very tedious.

I understand that you can make custom Logical Structure and the default for Map is this:

```
return entrySet().toArray();
```

Is there any way, either through custom Logical Structure or some plugin to view values for Map entries more useful than something like    `ConcurrentHashMap$WriteThroughEntry (id=193)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find that when I select a value in the "Variables" pane in the debugger, its value is shown below using the toString() method.  This works nicely for maps, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware I can expand each MapEntry to see the key and value.  However, this is very tedious if you want to locate an entry in a map of any reasonable size.

Comment: Can you please remove your answer since it does not address my question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you understood my answer.  If you simply select (ie click on it, making it be highlighted), the value you want to inspect, its toString() is shown in a nearby panel - no expanding required.

Comment: Thanks for clarify, you are right.  The window right below the variables panel shows the string equivalent...

Comment: For very large hashtables this is no good because the displayed value is truncated at 10,000 chars.

Answer (score 59):

You need to create a detail formatter on top of the logical structure. In the example screenshot you provided, your logical structure is ConcurrentHashMap$WriteThroughEntry. You can add the detail formatter by right clicking on a row containing a ConcurrentHashMap$WriteThroughEntry and selecting 'add detail formatter'.

I just knocked up this example using HashMap.

[image]

```
java.util.HashMap$Entry //  key + " - " + value
```

For a

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map;
```

.. I quickly populated with rubbish, I now see:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work on OS X in eclipse 3.7, I think because of Apple's JVM.  I get an error when I try to define a detail formatter for an inner class.  But this is how to do it.  Note that you can minimize the changes to the variables view by selecting the first radio button.

Comment: Please make the screenshot of the  "Variables" view a little larger and encircle the "Show logical Structure" button.

Comment: Although it's not perfect (the keys are not sorted), this works well enough, so here's the bounty.

Comment: for me it worked like this : getKey() + " - " + getValue() otherwise I had an error : Detail formatter error: <key> cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 11):

Well I made an ugly workaround. Set up this detail formatter for Map:

```
StringBuilder detail = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
for (Object k : keySet()) {
    detail.append((i++) + ": " + k + "\n");
}
return detail;
```

Then in the output of that, find the index of the entry with the key you want, then find that entry in the logical structure tree.

It works, but the detail formatter itself is a bit slow, and it requires an extra step. Also the keys are not sorted so finding the key you want in a large map may be difficult (though sorting could theoretically be done in the formatter).

Comment: I'm not sure for ConcurrentHashMap, but regarding java.util.HashMap, defining such a formatter is visibly superfluous as of Eclipse 2023-09 (JDT 3.19) with JDK 8. I am not an expert, but I suppose that's because JDK 8's AbstractMap.toString() does the job, while you must have used an older JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Show logical structure under the expressions window to make the values more readable. check this out
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/04/again-10-tips-on-java-debugging-with-eclipse/

Comment: Show logical structure sure is useful, but as you can see in his screenshot, it's already activated. He wants to avoid having to dig all elements.

Answer (score 0):

At least with JDK 8 and above (and a current Eclipse like 2023-09), I don't see why you'd need to do more than the preference change explained in the first (mandatory) step of [that answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262035/5405434).