# Is there a way to inspect map/set entries in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, dictionary

I have below code

```
Map<String, Employee> map1 = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
map1.put("delKey", new Employee());
map1.put("delKey1", new Employee());
```

When i inspect map1 under `variables view` with `show logical
structure` i just see value as Employee not an object so that i can inspect further employee object like below

[image]Is there a way i can debug key/value under map/set entries in eclipse

Comment: This should work in Eclipse when "Show logical structure" is on. Map is displayed as collection of its Entry objects.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275520/eclipse-debugging-hashmap-logical-structure-using-key-and-values-tostring-me) one too, few very good answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems to be correct. Have you created any attribute inside Employee class? I tried the following:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

And while debugging I could see the values:
[image: Debug View]

Answer (score 0):

You can do one more thing override the toString() method in your employee class & give you own custom way in which the object will be printed. Log the code. The employee values will be delineated in the console.

The preferred way is to check in the debug mode. Your debugger is not showing the employee attributes may be there would be none in the class, check your code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line at which you want to view the state of the map (It has to be in scope) and then run the program in Debug Mode.

The program will stop at the line with the breakpoint. In the window `Variable` you should be able to see all the variables that are in scope.

Comment: I know that. But my point entries  displayed under map/set are very confusing. Is there a good way ?

Comment: It is showing you the internal structure of `Map` It is important to `Map`. It may not be important to you. All the entries for the map are under the internal property table.