# Is it possible to display toString() result in value column in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, watch

Is it possible to display toString() result in value column in Eclipse debugger?

By default it displays values for built-in types and type name + id for user types:

[image]

Note, that debugger definitely CAN display `toString()`, but it does this only in separate section (below), not in `Value` column.

Answer (score 18):

It is possible, if a bit clumsy.

From the view's menu (hamburger icon), select *Java* → *Java preferences...* (to get to the "Detail Formatters" preferences section).

At the bottom, set **"Show variable details** ('toString()' value)" to:

- "**As the label for all variables**" (if toString() is enough for you):
  [image]
  Warning: this makes the "Type + ID" display vanish.
- or "As the label for variables with detail formatters" if you want to use your custom formatters.

Optionally (if you want to choose the details yourself), at the top (*Types with detail formatters*), define a simple return command for each type you want to inspect. Simple formatter for "not toString()":
[image: Detail Formatter for "other"]

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is excessive: no need to define any display formatters, `Show variable details` = `As the label for all variables` was found sufficient

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tried to present the basic and "excessive" way with screenshots and this took longer so the clarification came later, too ;) A matter of getting the most important info through the door :D

Comment: As worded, it implies that the "As the label for variables with detail formatters" option is needed to use custom formatters and the "As the label for variables" option will only use toString(). To be clear though, the detail formatters are overriding toString() and will be used in either case. These choices really control whether variables without detail formatters will use their toString() methods or the "Type + ID" format.

Comment: Is there a reason why that option is not the default? Could this hurt performance?

Answer (score 0):

If the object do not implement the `toString()` method you can define your own detail formatter. This assumes the object provide public methods to access the fields you are interested in. A good explanation can be found in the blog of [Codecentric: post about tips on java debugging with Eclipse](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/04/again-10-tips-on-java-debugging-with-eclipse/). Search for the tip "Human Readable Objects".

Answer (score -2):

I don't think thats possible, after all the debugger can't modify the program, it can just halt/modify the execution itself (like skipping method calls etc.). toString is a method like anything else and the debugger cant call it.

Comment: There is no need to modify the program, it is sufficient to call a method on the watched object during run time within the JVM. As @hiergiltdiestfu pointed out, custom formatters can be defined in the debugger.